# From where can i add People Card, Reputation Builder

Tags: 2013

Could not see where are these, are these webparts, is some feature needs to be activated for them to work???

Answer (score 0):

You need to both add the `Community Site Feature` to your site (it's a site feature) and I believe you need to add a Community app to your site as well. Once those two are done you should get access to all those webparts.